# Weird order of execution in threaded program

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2013

I'm attempting to execute a manager as thread by the code below. The weird thing that happens is that, as I dubug the code step by step, it seems that the `Stop()` method is called **before** the `Start()` method in the manager.

```
MyManager manager = new MyManager();
Thread thread = new Thread(manager.Start);
thread.Start();

while (Directory.GetFiles(pathToFiles).Length < 5)
  Thread.Sleep(1000);

manager.Stop();
thread.Join();
```

It's even weirder than that! **Sometimes** the execution order is as it's supposed to be. Then, as if something clogs the sanity, the breakpoint inside the `Stop()` method is hit **first** and the one in the `Start()` method later.

I'm suspecting something more intricate because on occasion, the program doesn't even hit the breakpoints while executed (and I execute in exact the same way)!

Not being a guru on threaded development, I need to know how to trouble-shoot this.

Comment: Does it work right when you aren't stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: Of course it works this way.  The CPU is free to be running whichever thread it wants whenever it wants.  If it wants to run one to completion before starting the other, switch half way through, at whatever point it wants, it can do any of those things.  This is entirely expected behavior.

Comment: @Savanna Nope. Same misbehavior. It works on a few occasions, failing at most.

Comment: @Servy I don't get it. It's **the same** thread I'm trying to start and **then** stop. It can't race against itself, can it?! Is it a Lucky Look thread whose shadow is faster than himself...?   :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten `thread.Start` needs to run before `manager.Stop`.  `manager.Start` doesn't even need to *start* executing before `manager.Stop` is called, but it could also be finished, or half done, or at any point in between.

Comment: @Servy I get **that** part. What I can' see is how it can execute the statement `manager.Stop()` **before** the while loop is done. (In fact, the files are created using **manager.Start** so the program shouldn't be able to get pass the sleeping part until they're created... What am I confusing?!)

Comment: @KonradViltersten It doesn't.  Either the condition is true, and you simply don't realize that, or you appear to think the `Stop` method is running before it is.  Another thread has nothing to do with this, really.

Comment: @Servy I assumed **precisely** what you said. Turns out that the stupid condition was indeed true. I aimed at a wrong, stupid  directory, one where there resided a bunch of stupid files that I negliged to remove. Because I'm stupid. It's almost 9 PM and I've been at work since 7 AM. So now I'm taking my bike and go home. Awesome help. Mucho thanko! (Also - I deserve to be slapped twice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a race condition. One thread races to call `Start`, the other races to call `Stop`. One of them reaches its goal first. Makes sense?

If you want Start to be called first, then call them in sequence:

```
Start();
...
Stop();
```

Comment: +1 for concise answer. Now, back to you. No, at this point **nothing** about the threads makes sense, hahaha. I thought I **did** call `Start` and `Stop` in this order. Don't I?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, you tell both of them to run in whatever order the CPU chooses, interweaving the contents of their methods as it sees fit.

Comment: Please bear with me, because I feel like a moron now. First I start the thread, then I wait for quite a while before the files are there (at least five of them). **First then** I execute the stop. The files aren't there **but** it already jumps to stopping. How?!

Comment: Apparently, you haven't waited long enough. Is your intention to have Start add 5 files? That would work if implemented correctly. There must be some bug that causes Start to be still running when the 5th file appears so that Start and Stop run simultaneously.

Comment: Servy's comments together with your answer = finally got it running well. Now I run home before it stops working again.   :)